# CWAC Camera - Restart Preview Triggers

Tags: android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I am working on a camera implementation similar to what Snapchat offers.
I have created a subclass of SimpleCameraHost to customize the directories and file paths and to handle saveImage(I am cropping the image into a square before I save it to disk). I have also subclassed CameraFragment as you(Mark) have in the demo.

I need to take three pictures(Take pic...user okays it...Move onto second pic..repeat...) before I continue with the flow of the app. I am using the single shot mode.  In the Oncreate() of the DemoFragment

```
    SimpleCameraHost.Builder builder =
            new SimpleCameraHost.Builder(new MyCameraHost(getActivity(), useFFC));

    setHost(builder.useSingleShotMode(true).build());
```

Question : I need to know how to prevent the cameraview from restarting 
the camera every time I pause the app while I'm on the 'okay the pic page'
and resume.Also if I leave the app idle on this page for a while, it seems to freeze and my camera cannot be started again(from any camera app including the default...I have to restart the device). I reckon this happens because I have not released the camera. Could you please direct me as to how I should handle pausing and resuming the app.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to prevent the cameraview from restarting the camera every time I pause the app while I'm on the 'okay the pic page' and resume

In the demo app, if I switch to single-shot mode, take a landscape picture using the rear-facing camera, press HOME from the photo-preview screen, return to the app from the recent-tasks list, and press BACK, everything behaves fine, at least on the Nexus 4 that I just tried it on.

Hence, I would suggest that you compare your app to the demo app and see where things differ that might cause this behavior.

If you feel that there is a bug in the library, feel free to [file an issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues), but you would need to give me a complete set of materials to be able to reproduce the problem. That would include details of the device (e.g., `Build.PRODUCT`), the code to reproduce it (if it is not one of the demo apps), and the steps I should manually follow to reproduce it.

> Also if I leave the app idle on this page for a while, it seems to freeze and my camera cannot be started again(from any camera app including the default...I have to restart the device)

Once again, I cannot reproduce this behavior. Immediately following the steps that I outlined above, I took another picture in single-shot mode, and left the app on the photo-preview screen while I composed the first part of this answer. I just pressed BACK, and everything is normal. So, again:

- Compare your app to the demo app, to see if you can determine what you may be doing that might cause this effect
- File an issue if you think that it is a bug in the library, but *only* do so if you can give me steps to reproduce the bug

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mark. In my app, I do not start a separate activity(Display Activity) to show the preview. I let the screen with the clicked pic remain(frozen screen i.e the DemoCamera fragment remain) and I toggle the visibility of a bunch of controls such as save, cancel, and take next picture. Now when I hit the home button(with demofragment currently displaying the captured pic) and then return to the app. The cameraview has restarted , although I should still be in the captured pic state in the fragment.

Comment: In Snapchat, when an image is captured and you are shown a bunch of options/controls on the screen and you hit home, then resume, the captured screen state of the cameraview remains. I need to achieve something like this.

Comment: @Rohan: That is not how `CameraView` is designed to work. Replacing the activity outright works, as is evidenced by the demo app. Replacing the `CameraFragment` ought to work. Leaving the `CameraFragment` up and not having the preview running is not supported. "I need to achieve something like this" -- then don't use the library, but work with `android.hardware.Camera` and `android.hardware.camera2.*` directly yourself. Or, switch to a different fragment/activity and use the captured photo as the background behind the "bunch of options/controls".